# Duplicate function calling in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one javascript function that used to display the menu and content in my web page. This is how I call this function :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     ViewProduct(action_name);
 });
```

So after my page load ready, It will call to this function. But the problem is, I have a search text box used to view the product that the user want to search.

```
    function SearchClick() { 
        if (typeof select_cat != 'undefined' && typeof select_dep != 'undefined') {
           action_name = "GetProductByCatSearch";
        }else if (typeof select_dep != 'undefined'){
            action_name = "GetProductByDepSearch";
        }else{
            action_name = "GetProductBySearch";
        }
        ViewProduct(action_name);  
    }
```

So when the SearchClick() is called, it produce the menu and product again. Then there are duplicate menu and content.

what I want is to skip the function in document.ready, when the function in SearchClick() is called.

Welcome to all solutions. Thanks so much.

Comment: show us what you are doing in ViewProduct

Comment: instantiate SearchClick() in place of ViewProduct()

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte : could you give me some example MatthewBlancarte?

Comment: @Shyju : It has many line of codes that's why I don't post in here Shyju.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is empty the menu first in the `ViewProduct` function. Function already executed can not be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check in `viewProduct()` if you have already shown the menu for that product then do nothing.